# why does the statement "v8::Isolate* isolate = v8::Isolate::New(create_params);"

Tags: v8

why does the statement:
v8::Isolate* isolate = v8::Isolate::New(create_params);
take 27 seconds to run?
This is from the "hello-world.cc" example from the V8 source.

Comment: on an old laptop, for me, it takes ~3s without snapshots, so I don't know.  Does it print out the result after it runs?  or is it maybe crashing and dumping core?

Answer (score 0):

I actually just got an answer from the Chromium team regarding this.  The long bootstrapping of an isolate is an intended behavior in debug mode.  To fix this, you can apparently either:

1. Build and link in release mode.
2. Use a snapshot to move the bootstrapping process from runtime to build time.